# how to fix these errors in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors

I finished my game but when I hit run, i'm getting these errors:

I need to change "JohnsPC" to my name!

```
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/JohnsPC/Desktop/Logo Mania?/Code/Yeah/PuzzleGame'

ld: library not found for -lChartboost
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And the second error I have no Clue

How do I fix these?

Comment: Have you looked through the project build settings?

Answer (score 1):

check the target - **Build Settings -> Library Search Path** and set proper path for library on your mac

also use macro `$(SOURCE_ROOT)` to avoid this kind of problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- Go to Targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries
- Click on + symbol & press Add Other
- Select your library